# No such column found error while updating sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I'm using following code to update my SQLite database.

```
fun updateTable(user: Users):Int{
        val db=this.writableDatabase
        val values=ContentValues().apply {
            put(USER_ID,user.userId)
            put(USER_NAME,user.name)
            put(USER_NUMBER,user.number)
            put(USER_STATUS,user.status)
            put(USER_IMAGE,user.image)
            put(ANY_MESSAGE_MADE,user.anyMessageMade)
        }
        val newRowId = db?.update(TABLE_NAME,values, USER_ID+ "="+user.userId,null)!!
        db.close()
        return newRowId
    }
```

But I got this error in my log and programn being crased

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: vV91XjGEgzIpV3235aYS
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.russvkm.chathut, PID: 4421
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: vV91XjGEgzIpV3235aYS (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE contact_entry SET name=?,user_status=?,anyMessageMade=?,userId=?,user_image=?,user_number=? WHERE userId=vV91XjGEgzIpV3235aYS
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1651)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1599)
        at com.russvkm.chathut.utils.CreateContact.updateTable(CreateContact.kt:78)
        at com.russvkm.chathut.fragment.ChatFragment.onClick(ChatFragment.kt:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

user id and table entry are available what I'm trying to update.

**I'm trying to update table with primary key which is userId**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of of the variable `user.userId` should be inside single quotes when you pass it to the `WHERE` clause of the `update()` method.
So the code should be:

```
db?.update(TABLE_NAME,values, USER_ID + " = '" + user.userId + "'", null)!!
```

but the correct and safe way to do this is with a `?` placeholder in the `WHERE` clause and passing the value of the parameter in the 4th argument of `update()`:

```
db?.update(TABLE_NAME, values, USER_ID + " = ?", arrayOf(user.userId))!!
```

But in your code there is also this line:

```
put(USER_ID,user.userId)
```

Why do you want to update the column `userId` with the same value that it already has?

Also the method `update()` returns the number of the updated rows and not any new `rowid`.
So what is the point of this line:

```
val newRowId = db?.update(TABLE_NAME,values, USER_ID+ "="+user.userId,null)!!
```

This makes me think that maybe you want to insert a new row in the table and not update an existing row.
If this is the case then you should use the method `insert()`:

```
val newRowId = db?.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)!!
```

Comment: i don't want to insert. newRowId is just if function return greater than one then value has been updated. Nothing but only to detect the update event. puting userId in single quote make sense let me check